# Can't figure out how to perform a function then navigate away with one button click. How can I do this?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart

I have a function that I've coded separately that performs fine when selected alone. It basically uploads some details to Firestore.

When I try to have it then Navigate back to the homepage on the same click, it navigates away but no file is made. SizedBox(

```
          SizedBox(
            width: 200,
            height: 75,
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                createEvent;
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/homePage');
              },
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50))),
              child: const Text(
                  'C R E A T E   E V E N T'
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: not sure what are you trying to do, maybe you just want to get the updated ui. for this add `await Navigator....(); setstate((){});`

Comment: @MDYeasinSheikh I'm trying to have it perform the createEvent function which uploads data to Firestore, then navigate away to a different page in one click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out the solution to this was in editing the createEvent code itself to perform the action rather than asking the button to do it. I simply added the line

```
  Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/homePage');
```

at the bottom of its code.

Answer (score 0):

Edited : sorry it forget to add the `then part`
do it as the folowing

````
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/homePage').then((){// do whatever u want});
}```
````

Comment: Thats already how it's written in onPressed?